# rename batch files, and add leading zero's before underscore

Tags: bash, rename, batch-processing, batch-rename

I have multiple files `Batch1_00000001` till `Batch9999_00000001` containing the following filenames:

```
Batch1_00000001.pdf
Batch10_00000001.pdf
Batch100_00000001.pdf
Batch1000_00000001.pdf
```

First of all I want to remove the word `Batch` and add the letter `b` to the front of the filenames. After that I want to add up to three leading zero's at the start. So that `b1_00000001.pdf` becomes `b0001_00000001.pdf` like:

```
b0001_00000001.pdf
b0010_00000001.pdf
b0100_00000001.pdf
b1000_00000001.pdf
```

Does anyone have a solution to break it all down, or make a single regex `rename` solution? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. [SO is a question and answer page for professional and enthusiast programmers](https://stackoverflow.com/tour). Please add your own code to your question. You are expected to show at least the amount of research you have put into solving this question yourself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try:

```
#!/bin/bash
cd /directory_contain_files
for file in *.pdf; do
        index=$(echo $file | cut -d'_' -f1 | grep -o "[0-9]*")
        if [[ $index -lt 10 ]]; then
                index="000$index"
        elif [[ $index -lt 100 ]]; then
                index="00$index"
        elif [[ $index -lt 1000 ]]; then
                index="0$index"
        fi
        mv $file b${index}_00000001.pdf
done
```

Comment: This is perfect, thank you for giving this example. I was fooling around with regex, but this is great. Especially the three steps: 10, 100, 1000. Thank you very much!